# PhpStorm cursor doesnt move on return in strings

Tags: phpstorm

When I press the `Enter` key while using PhpStorm when my cursor is in a string, the cursor doesn't move to the next line. It creates a new line, but the cursor remains in place. How can I change this?

[image: PhpStorm cursor issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's a bug.** It affects strings with injected SQL language.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56153 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

Comment: It would seem you are correct. I think a solution to this would be to use PDO. (Should probably use that anyways haha)

Comment: You may tell PhpStorm that this string is not SQL but just a plain text. This way no Language Injection will be in place (which means no syntax highlighting there as well as no code completion). For this you would need to write a comment before that string. Would that be acceptable for you? Alternatively you may just disable Language Injection rule for such language completely (in the IDE settings) and therefore no code modification would be needed.